# I want to post data to my database without page refresh when user clicks on anchor tag

Tags: jquery, laravel

The code is given below. I want to save my add id into database when user clicks on the anchr tag but this is not working.Now I have saved the id into a hidden text field but still not working. The id is not reaching the controller.

Comment: can you post your html as well?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no not getting error any where and now I saved the ad id into a hidden input field.

Comment: you cant put code controller??

Comment: I have given the link for Main controller code image

Answer (score 0):

[Image for main controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dETP8.png)Your syntax for Ajax is wrong. Check below the correct one

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery('#haha').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      jQuery.ajax({

         url: "{{ url('/mysavedadds') }}",
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
            ad_id: jQuery('$data->id').val(),
            _token:"{{csrf_token()}}"
         },
         success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
         }});
      });
   });
```

Controller function

```
function mysavedadds(Request $request)
{
 echo "<pre>";print_r($request->all());die;
 }
```

Comment: can you post the root from web.php file ie mysavedadds

Comment: Route::get("/mysavedadds","MainController@mysavedadds");

Comment: Route::post("/mysavedadds","MainController@mysavedadds")->name('mysavedadds');     Use this one

Comment: can you send me this function mysavedadds. That you have created in the MainController. Or you can send me the MainController file

Comment: I have given the link of the image for main controller code file above. Thanks

Comment: can you please check. The data you are sending on post request is received in controller or not
see my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

you need order you `ajax` try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery('#haha').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
     url: "url{{'/mysavedadds'}}",
     type: 'GET',
     data: {ad_id : $('#ad_id').val()},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function( data ) {
       console.log(data);
      }       
   })
  });
});
```

Comment: in your `controller function put (Request $request)` and you get id need on this `$request->ad_id`

Comment: The question specifies `POST`, not `GET`. Also, `JSON` is never mentioned anywhere...

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode he put in comment first answer route is `get` no `post`